# see EVERYTHING from cmd using python

Tags: python, cmd

I know how to use cmd via python and how to see the CMD output .
I would like to see everything from cmd(including the C:\user.... part or whatever folder im in)
anyone has an idea on how to do it?I tried but couldnt find a solution.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd

Comment: thank you very much but its not what i meant..i move between folders in the cmd via python and want to know on what folder im in the cmd

Comment: "The current working directory" means exactly the same as "what folder [I'm] in the cmd". If you mean something else, you'll have to show an example of the output you want.

Comment: when using the os.getcwd() method it return the folder in which the python file is,not the current working dictionery that im using in cmd via python

Comment: If you change directories inside the command string that you send to the OS, then you'll have to issue an OS "show the current directory" command _inside the command string itself_ . Your Python program can't get that information directly since the command string is being run in a separate subshell. BTW, what Python code are you using to send your command string to the OS?

Comment: os.system("command")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cmd` module, or even program straight in python with `subprocess.Popen()`